# Wildcarding vector templates

Tags: c++

I have to create vector of a special type depending on a user input.
e.g. the user has to choose if he wants to create a vector of ints or a vector of strings.
Is it possible to predefine a vector and define it clearly in a e.g. switch-case?

something like:

```
vector<WILDCARD> vec;
switch(input) {
case 1:
    vec = vector<int>()...
    break;

case 2:
    vec = vector<string>()....
    break;
....
```

Comment: Would a vector<boost::any> be any use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to predefine a vector and define it clearly in a e.g. switch-case?

No. C++ is a statically-typed language. That means, type of every variable must be known at compile time, and once its known, it cannot be changed later on - not even at compile-time. So what you're doing is not possible.

If you want to give users to choose the type. Then you can defined variables of all possible choices in each `case`, and works with the one which user chooses, something like this:

```
switch(input) {
case 1:
    { 
         std::vector<int> vec;
         //work with vec which is vector of int!
    }
    break;
case 2:
    { 
         std::vector<std::string> vec;
         //work with vec which is vector of string!
    }
    break;
    //....
```

Or if you fear code duplication then you can do this instead:

```
template<typename T>
void Work()
{
     std::vector<T>  vec;
    //work with vec of type T
}

switch(input) {
case 1:
    Work<int>();
    break;
case 2:
    Work<std::string>();
    break;
    //....
```

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot.
Create the vector in the switch case depending on switch case type.

```
switch(input) {
case 1:
    vector<int> vec1;
    vec1 = ...
    break;

case 2:
    vector<String> vec2;
    vec2 = ....
    break;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Since c++ is statically typed you can't do this.
But I guess [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html) or [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html) will get you close where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a statically typed language, so `vec` would have to have a predetermined type.

What you probably want to do is wrap what you're using as `vec` in an object, perhaps an abstract base class that doesn't mention what the vector base type is, and two child classes, one for `int` and one for `string`.  Then you'd use virtual functions to encapsulate the differences between the `vector<int>` version and the `vector<string>` version.